# Выравнивание картинки по центру div

Tags: html, изображения, css

есть html:

```
<div class="row">
          <? for($i=0; $i < count($alumni); $i++) { ?>
            <div class="span2">
              <img src="<?=$alumni[$i]['image'];?>">
            </div>
          <? } ?>
        </div>
```

есть css:

```
.row .span2 {
width: 135px;
height: 135px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
line-height: 135px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Нужно выравнивать картинку по центру, а она не выравнивается. Кто может подсказать другие способы?

Comment: Хорошая статья на habrahabr.ru [Абсолютное горизонтальное и вертикальное центрирование](https://habrahabr.ru/post/189696/) там все просто: выбираем соответствующий вариант и меняем параметры position и display если надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отцентровать вертикально?
Вы на верном пути.

Только по именам классов очень похоже, что вы используете `bootstrap 2`, а в этом фреймворке для классов `span*` задано `float: left`, что противоречит `display: table-cell`. Укажите явно `float: none`.

Answer (score 11):

Можно в **CSS** задать:

```
.row img{
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto; 
    }
```

Comment: только указать doctype надо)) честно, сталкивался, тогда не поможет)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


доктайп есть, но не помогло :(

Answer (score 1):

А сделать картинку фоном этого дива в бы не хотели?

```
.row {
    background: url(../img/картинка.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    width: 135px;
    height: 135px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.row .span2{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center; /*центрируем элемент по горизонтали */
    align-items: center; /* и вертикали */
    width: 200px; /* задали размеры блоку-родителю */
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden; /* если элемент больше блока-родителя – обрезаем лишнее */
}
```

Для img ничего прописывать не нужно. Любой блок внутри .row .span2 будет центрироваться сам.

Подробнее о центрировании при помощи флексбокса http://jedicss.com/css-kartinka-po-centru/

Comment: Поясните, почему вы считаете, что ваш ответ решит проблему ОП.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно по горизонтали и вертикали выровнять по центру, то так:

```
.row{
   position: relative;
}
.span2 {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .span2{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .span2 img{
        align-self:center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.span2{
    display: flex;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
}

.span2 img{
    display: block;
    object-fit: scale-down;
    object-position: center;

}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]